# Enum or related types to type hint varying combinations of string literals

Tags: python, literals, python-typing, typing

I have a function parameter called `price_type` that only allows arguments of either `A` (Ask), `B` (Bid), `M` (Mid), or any combination of them, for example: `AB` or `ABM`. The arrangement doesnt matter either, so `AB` is just as likely to be input as `BA`, and they are both valid.

```py
def __get_base_data(
    symbol: str,
    count: int,
    price_type: str, 
):
```

How can I type hint for `price_type`, such that I dont have to explicitly name every possible option? Doing something like

```
Literal["A", "B", "M", "AB", "BA", "AM" ....]
```

seems a little ridiculous to me. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe mapping `price_type` to a `str` is not ideal in your case, a possible solution is to create an enum `PaymentType` and map `price_type` to it. Since you can assign multiple `PaymentType`s you can also expect to receive a collection of `PaymentType` attributes.

```
from enum import Enum
from typing import Tuple

def __get_base_data(
    symbol: str,
    count: int,
    price_types: Tuple[PriceType, ...], 
):

class PriceType(Enum):
    A = 1
    B = 2
    M = 3
```